# How do I add colour to this specific code using Colorama in python?

Tags: python, colors

This is my code:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import random
colorama.init()
score = int(0)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------#
q1 = ("Work out the answer. 45 + 46 = ")
q2 = ("Kai buys a pair of shoes for £31 and a shirt for £67. Altogether, he spends £")
q3 = ("Work out the answer. 68 - 29 = ")
q4 = ("A bike normally costs £260. Its price is reduced in a sale by £90. The sale price of the bike is ")
q5 = ("Work out the answer. 32 x 30 = ")
q6 = ("A box holds 22 apples. The total number of apples in 20 boxes are ")
q7 = ("Work out the answer. 70 x 7 = ")
q8 = ("For a school show, 22 chairs are arranged equally in 30 rows. The total number of chairs is ")
q9 = ("A function machine changes 49 to 98 and changes 26 to '?'. The number in the question mark is ")
q10 = ("What number fills the gap? 35 x ? = 105. The number is ")
question = [
(q1, "91"),
(q2, "98"),
(q3, "39"),
(q4, "170"),
(q5, "960"),
(q6, "440"),
(q7, "490"),
(q8, "660"),
(q9, "52"),
(q10, "3") 
]

comments = ["Correct, you get one point, onto the next question", "At least I'm not the only smart one around here",
"Well done", "You must be really smart", "Some people have actually failed at that question...", 
"Congratulations", "Good work I guess...", "You actually got that right?!"]

 bcomments = ["Too bad, I have to take a point away, but I bet you got that wrong on purpose. Right...?",
         "I'm stealing your points!","You're a disgrace to mathematics",
         "You can't be serious... Can you?","Oops to you too...","Throw me your points!!",
         "Did you read the question properly?","Too bad...","I'm running out of ways to take your points...","Did you have to get it wrong??"]

colour = [(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE), (Fore.RED + Back.BLUE)]
```

This last line is the line where I have identified two colours to use using Colorama

```
random.shuffle(question)
for question, correctanswer in question:
answer = input(question + "")
if answer == correctanswer:
    correctA = 1
    print(comments[random.randrange(len(comments))])
    score = score + int(1)
    print("Your current score is " + str(score))
else:
    print("Wrong, the Correct answer is " + correctanswer)
    print(bcomments[random.randrange(len(bcomments))])
    if score>0:
        score = score - int(1)
    print("Your current score is " + str(score))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------#
input()
```

If I wanted to add colour to each presented question how would I do this? For example, how would I edit my code so that each question was displayed in a different colour?

Comment: I see you've taken neither aspect of [my advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119972/i-really-need-help-this-is-my-code-below-and-i-want-to-give-a-random-comment-fo#comment50252962_31119972) on-board. Have you read `colorama`'s documentation?!

Comment: See [_Colored Output_](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) section of colorama's documentation.